# How much time do I have after applicationDidEnterBackground invoked?

Tags: ios, background-process, uiapplicationdelegate, springboard

I want to send a timestamp to a remote server, and wait for the callback of success, then store the timestamp locally, if remote server did not respond.

Is it something that I could put into `applicationDidEnterBackground` implementation?

Answer (score 6):

According to iOS Developer Library [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a)

> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to
>   perform any tasks and return. If you need additional time to perform
>   any final tasks, you can request additional execution time from the
>   system by calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:. In
>   practice, you should return from applicationDidEnterBackground: as
>   quickly as possible. If the method does not return before time runs
>   out your app is terminated and purged from memory.
>
> You should perform any tasks relating to adjusting your user interface
>   before this method exits but other tasks (such as saving state) should
>   be moved to a concurrent dispatch queue or secondary thread as needed.
>   Because it's likely any background tasks you start in
>   applicationDidEnterBackground: will not run until after that method
>   exits, you should request additional background execution time before
>   starting those tasks. In other words, first call
>   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: and then run the task on a
>   dispatch queue or secondary thread.

So you have approximately **5 seconds** to perform any tasks and return in "applicationDidEnterBackground" methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do any network stuff before going to the background, you should ask for extra time with `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`.

Answer (score 0):

## You can do that in dispatch_async and you can wait the server answer and do something with your data, but you can't stop the enter background...

try this code

```
dispatch_queue_t savingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("savingQue", NULL);
dispatch_async(savingQueue, ^{

   //do something in bg.... 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


    });

});
dispatch_release(savingQueue);
```

Comment: Doest it need release even in ARC?

Comment: Seems not. I think it gets released later on.